# how to add a tablecellview dynamically with data in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I added the table cell view but I get the data in to the table view only when I scroll.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: its too less for help.. please put the code you are using so we can help you. Are you creating cell using UITableViewCell? Don't you get data for any cell without scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the `UITableView` when you are giving data to the custom cells of the `UITableView` like this `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Good Luck!